# How can I add Apps to the topmost (Title) Bar in Bluestacks?

Tags: bluestacks

I am using Bluestacks on my Windows 10 computer. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those tabs are for any app that's currently running - they're not shortcuts.